# Adding an IP-Exception to the Firewall

Tags: c#, firewall

I'm working on a project and for this, I need to ban an IP Address in the Firewall. But how do I do this in C#? I know so far:

```
public static INetFwMgr WinFirewallManager()
{
    Type type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(
        new Guid("{304CE942-6E39-40D8-943A-B913C40C9CD4}"));
    return Activator.CreateInstance(type) as INetFwMgr;
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    INetFwMgr manager = WinFirewallManager();
    //Adding the exception to the firewall
}
```

But now I don't know how I can add an Exception for an IP-Address.

Answer (score 5):

Check the solution from this [forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu-HU/csharpgeneral/thread/f6580aaf-ed47-4bb1-b976-6108595b8dfb):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using NetFwTypeLib;
namespace WinFirewall
{
    public class FWCtrl
    {
        const string guidFWPolicy2 = "{E2B3C97F-6AE1-41AC-817A-F6F92166D7DD}";
        const string guidRWRule = "{2C5BC43E-3369-4C33-AB0C-BE9469677AF4}";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FWCtrl ctrl = new FWCtrl();
            ctrl.Setup();
        }
        public void Setup()
        {
            Type typeFWPolicy2 = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid(guidFWPolicy2));
            Type typeFWRule = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid(guidRWRule));
            INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2 = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(typeFWPolicy2);
            INetFwRule newRule = (INetFwRule)Activator.CreateInstance(typeFWRule);
            newRule.Name = "InBound_Rule";
            newRule.Description = "Block inbound traffic from 192.168.0.2 over TCP port 4000";
            newRule.Protocol = (int) NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_.NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP;
            newRule.LocalPorts = "4000";
            newRule.RemoteAddress = "192.168.0.2";
            newRule.Direction = NET_FW_RULE_DIRECTION_.NET_FW_RULE_DIR_IN;
            newRule.Enabled = true;
            newRule.Grouping = "@firewallapi.dll,-23255";
            newRule.Profiles = fwPolicy2.CurrentProfileTypes;
            newRule.Action = NET_FW_ACTION_.NET_FW_ACTION_BLOCK;
            fwPolicy2.Rules.Add(newRule);
        }
    }
}
```

For a Windows XP solution check:
[Windows XP SP2 Firewall Controller](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10911/Windows-XP-SP2-Firewall-Controller)

Comment: But this code only works for Windows 7 and I want to run it on XP.

Comment: @DealerJoe: I added to answer for XP, hth